# Raspberry Pi 2 doesn't show css keyframe animation

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi 2 for a simple html kiosk application, but css animations doesn't show. I have tried Chromium and Iceweasel, but none of them seem to work. Does anyone have any useful information about this?

Comment: Does it work on a (Windows) desktop browser?

Comment: Yes – it is tested and works fine in Chrome and Firefox on windows and mac